# QUOTENAME equivalent function bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In Bigquery result I want to each and every field in double quote. I found QUOTENAME function is available in SQL not in big query Can anyone guide me how to achieve the same result in bigquery.

Thanks for your  help in advance
Regards
Amit

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT format('%T','abc')
```

returns

```
"abc"
```

**%t and %T behavior**

The %t and %T format specifiers are defined for all types. The width, precision, and flags act as they do for %s: the width is the minimum width and the STRING will be padded to that size, and precision is the maximum width of content to show and the STRING will be truncated to that size, prior to padding to width.

- %t is always meant to be a readable form of the value.
- %T is always a **valid SQL literal** of a similar type, such as a wider numeric type. The literal will not include casts or a type name, except for the special case of non-finite floating point values.

Read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=en_US#format)

Comment: I am getting the output in bigquery as expected but while saving data to google storage data is coming in triple quote"""abc""" I am using BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator to save the data on google.Could you please help me on this. Any way to store the data in double quote like "abc"

Comment: Storing is escaped, so triple quote is used, as when you use quoted sintax it means SQL valid. That's why is triple quoted.

Comment: How can I solve this, Because I want t o store data in "abc" in this way only

Answer (score 1):

You can use String formating Which is explained in details [Google Cloud Docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions)

Useage : 
`format("-%s-", 'abcd efg')`
Output : `-abcd efg-`

Comment: I am getting the output in bigquery as expected but while saving data to google storage data is coming in triple quote"""abc""" I am using BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator to save the data on google.Could you please help me on this. Any way to store the data in double quote like "abc"

Comment: I am getting the output in bigquery as expected but while saving data to google storage data is coming in triple quote"""abc""" I am using BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator to save the data on google.Could you please help me on this. Any way to store the data in double quote like "abc"

Comment: Well you might use escape character as it is mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Escaping-Strings-in-Transforms_57344768

Comment: Thanks all for your reply I am marking this as solved because I got the answer for this query actually I was opening the CSV file in notepad from google cloud storage which encrypt the data that's why in notepad it was showing in triple quote.